# Why api deployment failed with express, typescript, mysql, firebase-admin

Tags: typescript, express, deployment, pm2, helmet.js

First of all, i'm Korean so please understand my English mistakes..

I wanted to test deployment of my first backend api server(in `dev` branch), but every deployment I've tried has failed.
(test in local(build and start pm2) is always success)

Can you guys tell me why my api deployment failed

#### About my project

0. nodejs(v18), express, Typescript, cloudType(deploy platform from Korea)
1. authentication: firebase-admin
2. database: mysql(in aws RDS)
3. storage: aws S3
4. other package: `cors`, `cross-env`, `pm2`, `winston`, `winstom-daily-rotate-file`, `helmet`, `hpp`

#### server.js

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import categoryRouter from "./routers/categoryRouter";
import postRouter from "./routers/postRouter";
import sequelize from "./database";
import { Category, Choice, Post } from "./models";
import logger from "./logger";
import helmet from "helmet";
import hpp from "hpp";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: `http://localhost:3000`,
        credentials: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    })
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(morgan("combined"));
    app.use(
        helmet({
            contentSecurityPolicy: false,
            crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
        })
    ); 
    app.use(hpp());
} else {
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
}

app.use("/posts", postRouter);
app.use("/categories", categoryRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error(`${req.method} ${req.url} failed`);
    logger.error(error.message);
    res.status(404).json(error.message);
});
// association
Post.belongsTo(Category, {
    constraints: true,
    as: "category",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
});
Category.hasMany(Post, { sourceKey: "id", foreignKey: "categoryId" }); 
Choice.belongsTo(Post, { constraints: true, as: "post", onDelete: "CASCADE" });
Post.hasMany(Choice, { sourceKey: "id", foreignKey: "postId" }); 

const handleListening = () =>
    logger.info(`✅ Server listenting on port http://localhost:${PORT} `);

sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, handleListening);
    })
    .catch((error) => logger.error(error));
```

#### package.json(`npm run build && npm run start` is success when I tried in local)

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/hpp": "^0.2.2",
        "@types/morgan": "^1.9.4",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/multer-s3": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.245.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
        "helmet": "^7.0.0",
        "hpp": "^0.2.3",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "multer-s3": "^3.0.1",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
        "pm2": "^5.3.0",
        "sequelize": "^6.28.0",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "winston": "^3.8.2",
        "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"
    },
    "name": "myServer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon --watch src --exec 'npx' 'ts-node' ./src/server.ts",
        "build": "tsc",
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ./dist/server.js -i -1"
    },
    "author": "hello",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "here is description"
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
        "outDir": "dist",
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

#### firebase-config.ts

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
const params = {
    type: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_TYPE,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PROJECT_ID,
    privateKeyId: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    clientId: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CLIENT_ID,
    authUri: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_AUTH_URI,
    tokenUri: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_TOKEN_URI,
    authProviderX509CertUrl:
        process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
    clientC509CertUrl: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL,
};

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(params),
});

export default admin;
```

[github issues: more information of my files](https://github.com/kimyoungyin/yychoice__server/issues/2)